# If $a\neq 0$, there is a polynomial $p\in Q[x]$ such that $p(A)$ is the inverse of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let \begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\ 
0 & a & d\\ 
0 & 0 & a
\end{bmatrix} be a $3\times 3$ matrix where $a,b,c,d$ are integers. Then we must have

If $a\neq 0$, there is a polynomial $p\in Q[x]$ such that $p(A)$ is the inverse of $A$.

How can I prove this?

Since $a\neq 0$, I know inverse exist. Let us call the inverse $B$. We essentially wants to show that $B$ can be written as the linear combination of $A$(right?)

How do I approach this problem.

Hints are more welcome than the complete solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is $$\lambda^3-[\text{trace}\;{A}]\lambda^2+[\text{trace (adj }A)]\lambda-\det A=0.$$ So by Cayley-Hamilton $$A^3-[\text{trace}\;{A}]A^2+[\text{trace (adj }A)]A-a^3I=0,$$ so $$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{a^3}\left[A^2-(\text{trace}\;{A})A+(\text{trace (adj }A))I\right].$$  Thus $$p(x)=\frac{1}{a^3}\Big[x^2-\text{trace}(A)x+\text{trace (adj }A)\Big]$$ is the required polynomial.

Comment: I think there is a typo. It should be $x^2$ in the first term. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Is it ok now?